# Model validation from within the Service Layer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm interested in the idea of not having my BLL dependent on ASP.NET MVC. This means that I would like to have model binding occur within my service layer. But I want to take advantage of ASP.MVC's model validation as well. So I'm considering returning a custom validation dictionary from my BLL service methods like so

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "ADMIN")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(PostEditViewModel postEditViewModel)
    {
        BlogPost post = new BlogPost();

        postEditViewModel.MapTo(post);

        //returns custom validation dictionary
        var dic = _postService.CreatePost(post);

        //extension method that allows Controller ModelState to merge with customer error dictionary (returns ModelState)
        if (!ModelState.Merge(dic).IsValid)
            return View();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

and merge the returned validation errors with my Controller's `ModelState` using an extension method on `ModelStateDictionary` (the extension method will be part of the MVC application and not the BLL). Can anyone foresee any problems going down the road? Is there a more elegant or intelligent way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here? I've also considered [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-%28data%29/validating-with-a-service-layer-cs) approach.

Comment: Regarding your link, this seems to boil down to: work through a custom validation interface, wrap the ModelStateDictionary, pass it and update in the service; or (your option) return custom validation class, convert and merge to ModelStateDictionary? The steps involving the abstraction seem (to me) to be more-or-less equivalent, the real difference seems to be in the "pass-update" or "return-merge".  Would you agree?

Answer (score 5):

It feels somewhat awkward to answer a question this old, but there are some things that can be done.

---

First, I want to comment on the naming, simply from the fact that I'm currently building an ASP.NET app which is *very* large, and I've learned through the process that the `ViewModel` name becomes cumbersome, and is partially a lie. I've begun to name my 'View Models' as 'DTOs' instead, that is: Data-Transfer Object.

This has begun to make my code *much* more clear, as it's now obvious that the DTO can be a two-way object: data can be fed to it from the back-end or from the UI.

---

Regarding the service-layer handling database access: this is a good approach, I'll tell you that a lot of my code in this project I've mentioned previously is in the controller, and it's cumbersome. What I *would* change is reject the idea of needing to create a `dict` (or pass it to the `.Merge` method) controller-side, and do one of two things:

- Create a `BaseController` that will handle adding the validation errors to the `ModelState` itself, though this can become complicated.
- Pass the `Controller` to the method doing the validation, and allow it to add the errors to the `ModelState`.

It's been a while since I've touched ASP.NET MVC 3, but in 4 and 5 you can directly manipulate the `ModelStateDictionary`, and use `.Add` or `.AddModelError`. I do this on various validation methods to remove that responsibility from the controller, and reduce the call to:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "ADMIN")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(PostEditViewModel postEditViewModel)
{
    BlogPost post = new BlogPost();

    postEditViewModel.MapTo(post);
    _postService.CreatePost(post, this);

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View();

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

---

Another pointer: I would recommend converting your `Roles` attribute parameters to constants, I've found that it becomes unpleasant to change the name of a `Role` later, if you need to. I actually have a `Constants.Roles` class that has each role string associated to a type, so that if I have to change the name from `Controllers` to `Inventory`, it's *right there*, and my code can still reference the `InventoryControllers` constant. (You can also use the constants with XML-docs to make things more descriptive in the future.)

---

You have:

> ```
> BlogPost post = new BlogPost();
> ```

But then:

> ```
> var dic = _postService.CreatePost(post);
> ```

Be consistent. If you're using `var` in one location, use it in the others. I used to be anti-`var` period because I felt it made my code look less organized, but to be honest, it helps align all the variable names to the fifth textual column (counting the space), so it's easy to identify where something is declared. (Of course, with the highlighting Visual Studio does it's not necessary, and F12 is a wonderful tool, but it's still helpful at times.)

It also allows you to *ignore* what type it is when declaring. I'd have to type `BlogPost` out in one of those two places on that line (though one can argue that with intellisense when you type `BlogPost thing = new` it automatically suggests `BlogPost()` to finish it) so I don't mind changing the manual typing from `BlogPost post =` to `var post = new BlogPost();`, personally I type faster that way anyway.